# $\sigma$-finite measure on $\mathbb{R}$ that maps half-open intervals to $\infty$

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Consider $\mathbb{R}$ equipped with the Borel-$\sigma$-algebra $B$ and a measure $\mu : B \rightarrow [0, \infty]$. The measure $\mu$ is called $\sigma$-finite, if there is a sequence $A_1,A_2,...$ of sets in $B$ so that $\bigcup_{n\geq1}A_n=\mathbb{R}$ and $\mu(A_n)<\infty \ \ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$.
Now the question: Is there a $\sigma$-finite measure on $(\mathbb{R},B)$ so that for all $a<b$ we have $\mu ((a,b])=\infty$?

To assume the existence of such a $\mu$ and then get a contradiction, it would be sufficient to show that the interior of one of the $A_n$ is non-empty.I tried to show this using Baires category theorem. This, however, only tells me that there must a $m \in \mathbb{N}$ so that the interior $\textbf{of the closure}$ of $A_m$ is non-empty. I don't think this is sufficient.
Am I wrong and there actually is such a $\mu$? If not, how can I prove the nonexistence? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Define $\mu(A) = |A \cap \mathbb{Q}|$, where $|.|$ denotes the cardinality which is either finite or countable (in which case we say the value is $+\infty$).
This is a valid measure on all subsets of the reals, so certainly defined on $B$.

Then taking $A_0 = \mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}, A_n = \{q_n\}, n \ge 1$ in some enumeration of the rationals (so $\mathbb{Q} = \{q_n: n \ge 1\}$), shows that $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite, but every open interval contains infinitely many rationals, so has measure $+\infty$.

Comment: hey! thanks for the great answer. how did you make up this $\mu$?
the only thing I am asking myself is if this is really $\sigma$-additive. I will try to prove that.

Comment: @Joker123 I gave the decomposition to show it is $\sigma$-finite. The idea that we can extend the counting measure on the rationals in this way is a standard construction in measure theory, and using the density of the rationals seemed logical (because we wanted open sets to have big measure).